# Give me an example of a differential operator that is normal, not self-adjoint and has application in Physics

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, eigenfunctions

I am looking for an example of a differential operator whose domain is the Hilbert space of square integrable functions with real $N$-dimensional domain $L^2(\mathbb R^N)$ having the following characteristics:

1. the operator is a linear combination of derivatives up to order 2;
2. the operator is normal, but not self-adjoint;
3. the operator's adjoint is known and is provided in the answer with an adjointness proof (or at least a sketch of the proof).
4. the operator has application in Physics (please, provide a sketch of the application).
5. the operator has non-trivial eigenfunctions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check the momentum operator on the real half-line ? IIRC it is symmetric with no self-adjoint extension as the von Neumann deficiency indices are unequal.

Comment: Unfortunately, this operator, as usually defined for square integrable functions $\Psi$ such that $\Psi(0)=0$, has no eigenfunctions, which violates (5).

Comment: By "not self-adjoint" I guess you mean "not symmetric". Do you mean a real Hilbert space? I don't think an operator satisfying 1 can have discrete eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't mean a real Hilbert space. By self-adjoint, I mean self-adjoint; a symmetric operator is not necessarily self-adjoint.

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean by "real" in the first sentence. Any symmetric operator of this form is self-adjoint by Nelson's theorem. If you transform to the Fourier domain it is apparent that there are no discrete eigenvalues. BTW, you automatically get notifications of comments under your questions, but I don't unless you put @KeithMcClary .

Comment: "real N-dimensional domain" means that the functions are defined over the $R^N$ vector space. It does not mean the functions are real-valued. For example, $f(x) = \imath x$, $x \in R$ is a complex-valued function defined over a real domain. Moreover, I haven't asked for discrete eigenvalues. I want it to have nontrivial eigenfunctions, which means it has eigenfunctions associated to non-zero eigenvalues.